# Confusion around brackets, closing out an array

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to write a file which sends a POST request to an API with specific json data and headers.

This is what I am trying to replicate:

This is my PHP code:

```
$url = 'http://api.local/rest/users';
$data = '{"4":"four","8":"eight"}';

$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN','x-api-key: APIKEY,'x-proxy-global-company-id: COMPANYID'));

$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

This results in the following error:

> unexpected 'x' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in your code on line 9

As far as I can see I have closed out my brackets on the array correctly. Could anyone please give a novice PHP programmer a bit of help on this one please.

Comment: Missing ' after APIKEY...

Comment: Check the syntax highlighting missing `'` here `'x-api-key: APIKEY`

Comment: also, you should probably get accustomed to using `[]` in place of `array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing quote after APYKEY

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN',
    'x-api-key: APIKEY','x-proxy-global-company-id: COMPANYID'));
```